# How do I set model variables within an acceptance test?

Tags: ember.js

In Ember.js, I currently want to test a UI feature present. Essentially, once a model variable changes, I expect to see a UI element appear (a checkmark). I have tried creating a model within the acceptance test but this unfortunately did not work as I did.

I just wanted to know which function to use to set model variables.

Answer (score 0):

A model typically would involve unit tests, but like you've said you're testing the visual result of something being set on a model. I would recommend an integration test. If you are able to refactor (or maybe this is the case already), the part of the template into a component then you can create an ember test for the component and pass in the model set up perfectly how you would like.

If this test really does depend on the model being setup a specific way I would look at how your application sets up that model to begin with and try to replicate those actions with `click` and `fillIn` helpers. Another way is say, your application wants to setup a user but relies on a network request to do this, then you could use `pretender.js` and fake the response to that request so that the application's inputs are setup from the network in the way you're after.

I would really try to do this an acceptance test though, the composable nature of components allows them to be tested in stricter isolation, these tests will run faster, and you're worrying less about side effects.